# Point multiplication implementation using double and add method in java

Tags: java, double, addition, point, multiplication

I'm trying to implement the double and add method of scalar multiplication of ECDSA based on the pseudo code below:

```
Algorithm 1 (Double-and-add) 

    input P

    Q ← P

    for i from l−2 to 0 do

        Q ← 2Q

        if i = 1 then Q ← Q + P 

    output Q
```

And here is my java code:

```
public static ECPoint ScalarMulti(BigInteger ks, ECPoint G) {
    String k = ks.toString(2);
    ECPoint q = new ECPoint(zero, zero);
    q = G;
    for (int i = k.length() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        q = DoublePoint(q);
        if (k.substring(i, i + 1).equals("1")) {
            q = Pointaddition(q, G);
        }
    }
    return q;
}
```

}

But the signature verification is always failed (I am sure there are no mistakes in other codes), what is the problem here? Is the pseudo code correct? If it is, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: the verification is failed. I've used another method to implement the double and add method, and the verification is successful

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of code you provided it is the best java code possible to implement your algorithm. Your code was containing logical errors.

```
public static ECPoint ScalarMulti(BigInteger ks) {
    ECPoint p = new ECPoint(zero, zero);
    ECPoint q = p;
    for (BigInteger i = obj.subtract(new BigInteger("2")); //initialization
            i.compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) >= 0;  // comparision
            i = i.subtract(new BigInteger("1"))) {  // increment
        q = DoublePoint(q);
        if (i.compareTo(new BigInteger("1")) {
            q = Pointaddition(p, q);
        }
    }
    return q;
}
```

Comment: sorry but the type of ks is BigInteger and it cannot change to int directly?

Comment: Sorry, I have not noticed that. Well I don't know why are you using BigInteger though, It would be more easy if your would be using Double or Integer. And I want to mention 1 thing that it would be good to first make final instance of BigInteger of 0, 1, and 2 that are used amid, but to make code much equivalent to your algorithm I did that. @jessica